# How can I predict the next number give prior history of known sequences?

Tags: probability

I have a simple problem where I want to present a user with a list of possible choices for the next step in a workflow process. The issue is as follows: A particular user of a software program uses certain workflows, by which I mean a certain set of commands in sequence. Each command has a unique numeric value. The numeric values in any one sequence have no relation to each other. That is, this isn't an attempt to detect the next number in some formulaic sequence.

As the user is using commands to perform tasks, I want to predict which command, or commands, the user is most likely to use next. I could build out a tree-like structure where each node is a command (numeric) identifier and walk the tree and present the next set of nodes at a branching node as a good guess. But I am looking for more of a mathematical approach.

Here's the easiest example. The user starts our program. The first command is almost always either a file open command or create a new file command.

Here's another example. The user starts our program and creates a new file. The user creates a shape and then executes a command to create a hole in the shape (this is a mechanical design/engineering application). After creating a hole the user is most likely to either run a thread command or a counter-bore command to modify/attribute the hole. I would like to capture the command sequence data over time and start presenting the user with a palette of command choices that changes dynamically. That is, I want an "intelligent toolbar" user interface that modifies itself as the user is working with the system.

What should I consider? For example, is this something a Markov chain can be used to do?

Comment: There is a huge literature in Computer Science on user interface design. Your users might be better served if you looked into that literature or asked your question on a Computer Science forum rather than on MSE. (If I was responding to your question on such a forum, I might strongly advise you to find out what your users want before presenting them with what you think they want: unpredictable context-sensitive behaviour in a user-interface can be massively distracting and give a big increase in the workload for the user.)

Comment: Users don't often know what they want until we show it to them. I've been programming for 35 years and am very familiar with UX. We have plenty of tips, prompts and suggestion interface elements as the user works through their design. This includes MRU and MFU command UI elements (context menus) and I want to extend this by adding a bit of AI that can use the telemetric data we collect as we observe how a user is using the product to predict what the user will do next based on previous history. The aim is to improve the UX by reducing the number of clicks it takes to get to the next command.

Answer (score 1):

You MIGHT be able to implement this with a Markov chain model. However, it is likely that aside from the obvious chance fluctuations, you will also need to consider more than one instruction back, which may make an effective model quite large.

Comment: +1. "quite large": not really, in my opinion. You can have a history of up to 3 or even 4, since the number of commands is going to be 'small' compared to other things Markov models are used for, like English text. Training the model might be hard, however.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good candidate for a Machine Learning approach:  constructing a decision tree to predict the next command based on the previous commands.

Comment: Besides Markov, I think at least other one approach to take is to build a graph and base decisions on an analysis of the graph. I'm guessing that web browser search key-ins use that approach - as you type a phrase, the controls drop a list of suggestions based on previous history of like searches. Google probably has one huge graph system. Thanks for the answers!